# Sharing Properties between React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties, components

I'm building a sort of clock with React that has an option to increment or decrement a number (25 as default) in one component, and in another component it updates the timer (25:00 since we start at 25) to whatever the number is incremented or decremented to.

I have two components (Session and Clock) successfully performing their own actions, however I'm stumped as to how I can get the counter (Session component) to update the state of the timer in the Clock component. More specifically, I've been toying with `this.props.minutes` to no avail.

Question: How can I go about sharing the `this.state.minutes` property among components? Thank you in advance. I'm still a total beginner at React.

Session:

```
const Session = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      minutes: 25,
      seconds: 0
    };
  },

  increment: function() {
    this.setState({ minutes: this.state.minutes + 1 });
  },

  decrement: function() {
    this.setState({ minutes: this.state.minutes - 1 });
  },

  timeToString: function(time) {
    return time + ':00';
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <section>
        <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
        {this.state.minutes}
        <Clock/>
      </section>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = Session;
```

Clock:

```
const Clock = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return { currentCount: 10 };
  },

  startTimer: function() {
    var intervalId = setInterval(this.timer, 1000);
    this.setState({ intervalId: intervalId });
  },

  pauseTimer: function() {
    clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    this.setState({ intervalId: this.state.currentCount });
  },

  timer: function() {
    var newCount = this.state.currentCount - 1;
    if (newCount >= 0) {
      this.setState({ currentCount: newCount });
    } else {
      clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <section>
        <button onClick={this.startTimer}>Start</button>
        <button onClick={this.pauseTimer}>Pause</button>
        {this.state.currentCount}
      </section>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = Clock;
```

Comment: For parent-child communication, simply pass props.
https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass in the state from Session to Clock like so:

`<Clock time={this.state.minutes} />` in your Session component

Then the 'state' is now available to your Clock component as `this.props.time`

or whatever you call it in the above code.

The moral of the story is that state passed down to from a parent component to a child component is done so using props

Relevant Docs:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html

Edit: another key link in the docs:

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't realize that.

Comment: Same thing happened to me!, its a common mistake I'm sure